# How to prevent clicking on empty stage or at least identify it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I've added a number of movieclip instances (a simple image of an apple)on to the stage at random x and y. Now I am trying to click on each one to remove them.

Here is my code:

```
public function Apples() {

    for(var count:int=1; count<=10; count++){
        var apple = new Apple();
        apple.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        apple.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;    
        apple.name = count;
        stage.addChild(apple);
        }

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);



    function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
        var displayObject:DisplayObject = (DisplayObject) (e.target);
        displayObject.parent.removeChild(displayObject);
        }
}
```

My problem is that I want to be able to figure out when all of the apples have been removed.

I've tried by adding a simple counter on every `onClick` call, so that once it reaches the same number of apples displayed, I display a game over message, but the problem here is that if you click on the empty stage rather than the apple, then the count still increases.

Is there a way to prevent the user from clicking on the stage, or a way to identify if the stage has been clicked on for an if condition?

Or maybe there's an entirely other way to achieve what I need?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding `Apple` instaces to the stage you can check if an Apple is clicked inside your onClick handler

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var apple:Apple = e.target as Apple;
    if(apple) {
       apple.parent.removeChild(apple);
    }
}
```

If you don't click on an apple the apple instance will be null.

I would probably keep the apples in an array and remove them from the array once they are removed from the stage/parent. Then all you need to do to check if there are apples left on stage is to check the length of that array.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Unfortunately, haven't learned arrays yet :)